# render blob to popup div instead of opening in new window

Tags: javascript, blob

Currently I can download a blob and render it in a new window like this:

```
const blob = new Blob([downloadEvent.response], { type: mimeType });

const URL = window.URL || (window as any).webkitURL;

const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

window.open(blobUrl);
```

Is it possible to somehow open the blob in a popup div instead of a new window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an iframe should work:

```
 const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
 iframe.src = blobUrl;
 /*your favorite DOM node */.appendChild(iframe);
```